# Android - How to set width of <animation-list> or <item>s in it?

Tags: android, animation, imageview, width

I'd like to ask you for help with setting a right width to my ImageView. I've got an animation going it my ImageView and its width spreads all over my display. I need to have the width of it only about 50dp, not more.

My `ImageView`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/darkgrey" >

    <TableLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >    
        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/imgdesc"
                android:padding="15dp" />
    </TableLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

An animation XML - `anim_lytkove_vyskoky.xml`:

```
<animation-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:oneshot="false"
    android:id="@+id/kat1_lytkove_vyskoky" >

    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/kat1_lytkove_vyskoky_1" 
        android:duration="500" />
    <item 
        android:drawable="@drawable/kat1_lytkove_vyskoky_2" 
        android:duration="500" />

</animation-list>
```

Comment: `sp` is intended for text only, for images you should use `dp` or `dip`

Comment: @AndersonSilva: OK, thanks, but what about my problem? It's still there

Comment: You should show more code, I've just run an example just like yours and works fine. Check this out to see if you are missing something http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/AnimationDrawable.html

Comment: @AndersonSilva: Which part of code I should add? In java code I've got exactly what is in the link you've posted. It's working, but it's too wide, I just need to shrink the width of the animation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the `TableLayout` (or switch it for a `TableRow`)

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@color/darkgrey" >

    <TableRow
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/image"
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:contentDescription="@string/content_desc"
                android:padding="15dp" />
    </TableRow>

</ScrollView>
```